# Update Query from a Lookup Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, nested, ms-access-2007

I have a spreadsheet that I am converting to an Access DB.  I have a column of typed out customer names that I want to replace with the appropriate customer number from our accounting system.

I have created a table with the customer info, and a query that shows what ID needs to be inserted into the source data.  What I'm looking for is:

```
UPDATE tblStarting_Data
SET CustomerID=x
WHERE TEMPCustomer=y
```

Where X and Y come from qryIDPerCustomer.

Can I use a loop?  How do I reference another query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility in MS Access (object names borrowed from Tomalak answer):

```
UPDATE tblStarting_Data, qryIDPerCustomer
SET tblStarting_Data.CustomerID=qryIDPerCustomer.CustomerID
WHERE tblStarting_Data.TEMPCustomer=qryIDPerCustomer.CustomerName
```

Comment: +1 -- I was unsure if Access supported updating a joined query (a few years ago I would have known by heart... *sigh*). I had to fire it up and try it out.

Comment: I think it doesn't support usual T-SQL construct "update x set a=y.b from x join y" and it doesn't support joining with aggregate query, other variants usually work. But I've no MS Access here to check out exact rules; so haven't I written Access queris for year or two :)

Comment: I was a bit unclear with the request.  Your code ends up being

    UPDATE tblStarting_Data, qryIDPerCustomer
    SET tblStarting_Data.CustomerID=qryIDPerCustomer.CustomerID
    WHERE tblStarting_Data.OpportunityID=qryIDPerCustomer.OpportunityID

You got me close enough to what I needed though, THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I think a JOIN will help you:

```
UPDATE 
  tblStarting_Data AS sd 
  INNER JOIN qryIDPerCustomer AS qc ON sd.TEMPCustomer = qc.CustomerName
SET 
  sd.CustomerID = qc.CustomerID;
```

This can be expressed as a correlated sub-query as well (though the join syntax is preferable):

```
UPDATE 
  tblStarting_Data
SET 
  CustomerID = (
    SELECT  CustomerID 
    FROM    qryIDPerCustomer
    WHERE   CustomerName = tblStarting_Data.TEMPCustomer
  )
```

No need for a loop, both statements will update all records in `tblStarting_Data` in one step.

Comment: I couldn't get your method to work...  It makes sense when I read it, but in code it just won't execute.

Comment: Your correlated sub-query syntax, despite being valid Standard SQL-92 syntax, is not supported by ACE/Jet (even in its own ANSI-92 Query Mode!)