# MS-ACCESS: Deleting all rows except for top 1 and updating a table from a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I'm almost done with this, just a few last hiccups. I now need to delete all records from a table except for the top 1 where readings_miu_id is the "DISTINCT" column. In other words words i need to delete all records from a table other than the first DISTINCT readings_miu_id. I am assuming all I need to do is modify the basic delete statement:

```
DELETE FROM analyzedCopy2
WHERE readings_miu_id = some_value
```

But I can't figure out how to change the some_column=some_value part to something like:

```
where some_column notequal to (select top 1 from analyzedCopy2 as A 
where analyzedCopy2.readings_miu_id = A.readings_miu_id)
```

and then I need to figure out how to use an UPDATE statement to update a table (analyzedCopy2) from a query (which is where all of the values I want stored into column RSSI in table analyzedCopy2 are currently located). I've tried this:

```
UPDATE analyzedCopy2 from testQuery3 SET analyzedCopy2.RSSI = 
(select AvgOfRSSI from testQuery3 INNER JOIN  analyzedCopy2 on analyzedCopy2.readings_miu_id =  testQuery3.readings_miu_id where analyzedCopy2.readings_miu_id = testQuery3.readings_miu_id) 
where analyzedCopy2.readings_miu_id = testQuery3.readings_miu_id
```

but apparently I can't use FROM inside of an update statement. Any thoughts?

I'm sure I'm going about this a very nonstandard (and possibly if not probably the flat out wrong) way but I'm not being allowed to use vb.net2008 to pull and manipulate then store the data like I would like to so I'm stuck right now using sql statements in ms-access which is a good learning experience (Even if trying to do such odd things as I've been having to do in sql statements is making me beat my head against my deck *figuratively of course*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS Access UPDATE sql statements cannot reference queries, but they can reference tables.  So the thing to do is store the query results into a table.

```
SELECT YourQuery.* 
INTO TempTable1
FROM YourQuery
```

Now you can use TempTable1 in an UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE TargetTable
INNER JOIN TempTable1 ON TempTable1.TargetTableId = TargetTable.Id
SET TargetTable.TargetField = TempTable1.SourceField
```

See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871905/use-select-inside-a-update-query).

Comment: yay!!, thanks. that worked for that part now i have to either figure out how to delete all rows (records) from analyzedCopy2 that are not the first distinct readings_miu_id or figure out how to modify a code like this:

SELECT top 1 *
from  analyzedCopy2 as A
where readings_miu_id = A.readings_miu_id

to get what i need.

Comment: How do you define the first distinct readings_miu_id?  Does it have a date?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a copy of access on this machine, and it's been a few years since I dabbled in access, so I'm taking a wild stab here, but can you do a

```
delete from analyzedCopy2
where readings_miu_id not in (select top 1 readings_miu_id from analyzedCopy2 order by...)
```

(you'll need the order by to get the proper top 1 record, order by the id maybe?)

I've got no hope of helping you with the second one without a copy of access. I know how I'd do it in TSQL, but access is a whole different kettle of wtf's :-)

Comment: thats kinda close but it deletes all records where readings_miu_id isn't equal to the top readings_miu_id in the entire table instead of deleting only the duplicate readings_miu_id's rows. I tried this:

delete from analyzedCopy2 as A
where readings_miu_id not in (select top 1 readings_miu_id from analyzedCopy2  where analyzedCopy2.readings_miu_id = A.readings_miu_id order by readings_miu_id)

but it doesn't delete anything. as far as i can tell this is because im looking at the value of top 1 readings_miu_id (which is all of them when i do it this way) instead of the entire record of top 1

Comment: Uh, I read your original question as asking for exactly what this gives you -- you want to delete everything but the TOP 1, and that's precisely what Dan's SQL gives you. Perhaps you need to edit your question. This should be completely doable without a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make too complicated, since all of the records that i needed to pull had the same information in each field that i needed all i had to do was use:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT readings_miu_id, DateRange, RSSI, ColRSSI, Firmware, CFGDate, FreqCorr, Active, OriginCol, ColID, Ownage, SiteID, PremID, prem_group1, prem_group2
FROM analyzedCopy2   
ORDER BY readings_miu_id;
```

in order to pull the top 1 record per readings_miu_id.