# Speed up a UPDATE with SELECT query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, optimization

I have two tables:

- Table 1 has Episode and Code, with Episode as distinct.
- Table 2 has Episode and Code, but Episode is not distinct (other fields in the table, not relevant to the task, make each row unique).

I want to copy Table 1's Code across to Table 2 for each episode.  The current code to do this is as follows:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET Table2.Code = (SELECT TOP 1 Code FROM Table1 WHERE Episode = Table2.Episode)
```

This takes hours and hours.  (I don't know precisely how many hours, because I cancelled it at about the 20 hour mark.)  They *are* big tables, but surely there's a faster way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a SQL Server handy and I'm not completely sure, but I seem to recall there was a syntax like the following which should probably speed things up.

```
 UPDATE Table2 SET Table2.Code = Table1.Code FROM Table1 
 WHERE Table1.Episode = Table2.Episode
```

Comment: The join might belong in the update clause, but I've never tried it myself:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871905/use-select-inside-a-update-query

Comment: I know I have tried it, but now it's too late and I'm sleepy :-). I think the syntax's correct using an implied join and your link uses an explicit join.

Comment: Wow.  That turned it into a 6 minute query instead of a 20 hour one.  :O.  ...Now to verify the result sets are the same...

Comment: Add some indexes on Episode in both tables and you might be able to shave it down to under a minute.

Comment: Yes indexes would be due in both tables as well

Answer (score 1):

Are there any indices on the "Code" and "Episode" columns on both tables? Those would definitely help speed up things quite a bit!

Marc

Answer (score 1):

You can use UPDATE with joins like this. Note that you have to specify `FROM`.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColVal = O.NewVal
FROM MyTable T
INNER JOIN MyOtherTable O ON T.Id=O.Id
WHERE ...
```

http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ua-uz_3.htm