# Difficulty in creating update totals query on same table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, sql-update, aggregate

Consider the following table:

```
ID nonUniqueID value total
--------------------------
1  12345        5     x
2  12345        10    x
3  789          20    x
4  789          5     x
```

I need to make a query something like this (psuedo SQL), which will work within Access 2007:

```
UPDATE table 
SET total = SUM(value) 
WHERE nonUniqueID IS SAME;
```

The result should be as follows:

```
ID nonUniqueID value total
--------------------------
1  12345        5     15
2  12345        10    15
3  789          20    25
4  789          5     25
```

I've tried group bys, but I got odd results that quite frankly, I could not interpret. Does anybody know how I could achieve something like this?

Comment: Due to Access's limitations, I found the easiest solution was to do a select statement, and then looping through the result set in VBA to run the updates.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this works in Access or not, but give it a try:

```
update table t1
inner join (
    select nonUniqueID, sum(value) as SumValue
    from table
    group by nonUniqueID 
) t2 on t1.nonUniqueID = t2.nonUniqueID
set t1.total = t2.SumValue
```

**Update:** Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871905/use-select-inside-a-update-query), it looks like it is not going to work. But give it a shot! If it doesn't, you can use the approach suggested in that question.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible option:

```
update t 
set total = (select SUM(value) from table where nonUniqueID = t.nonUniqueID)
from table t
```