# UPDATE SET SELECT error "Operation must use an updateable query"

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have an Access database with an item table "VendorItem" with (ID, Vendor, Price) Fields and another "ItemPrice" with (ItemName, AveragePrice) Fields.

I want to run an SQL query that will update the average price of the item from a specific vendor, let's say 'xxx'.

The error I get is "Operation must use an updateable query". This code is simple but I haven't been able to find the cause of this error.
How could I change the string to get what I want?

I have:

```
Sub MP()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "UPDATE ItemPrice SET AveragePrice=(SELECT AVG(Price) FROM VendorItem WHERE Vendor='xxx') WHERE ItemName='xxx'"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like ms access doesn't like aggregate functions in update. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/q/871905/1385896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access domain functions can be used to avoid the "must use updateable query" complaint.  In this case, use the [DAvg Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/davg-function-HA001228815.aspx).

First test this as a new query in the query designer.  Adjust as needed, then adapt your code to use the working SQL.

```sql
UPDATE ItemPrice
SET AveragePrice = DAvg('Price', 'VendorItem', 'Vendor="xxx"')
WHERE ItemName='xxx'
```