# Access Update SQL with Sum Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I am using access as my DB to try to Sum the number of test attempts by subject for each Student for a SchoolGrade. Some basic info: A SchoolGrade has many students, a students test attempts are record by subject. I am wanting to update the total test attempts taken by subject for each SchoolGrade.
Below is my query:

```
UPDATE [SchoolGrade] AS SG
INNER JOIN [Student] AS S ON S.schoolgrade_id = SG.id
SET SG.[Total Reading Test Attempts] = SUM(S.[Reading Test Attempts] ), 
SG.[Total Math Test Attempts] = SUM(S.[Math Test Attempts] ), 
SG.[Total Science Test Attempts] = SUM(S.[ScienceTest Attempts] );
```

I am getting the following error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression 'Total Reading Test Attempts' as part of an aggregate
>   function.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be complete, here's a full set of queries to perform the update and clean up afterward.  All due credit to Gordon Linoff's answer and [Use SELECT inside an UPDATE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871905/use-select-inside-an-update-query).

Create table:

```
SELECT s.schoolgrade_id,
             SUM([Reading Test Attempts]) as sum_reading,
             SUM([Math Test Attempts]) as sum_math,
             SUM([Science Test Attempts]) as sum_science
INTO TempTable
FROM [Student] AS s
GROUP BY s.schoolgrade_id
```

Perform update:

```
UPDATE SG
SET [Total Reading Test Attempts] = s.sum_reading, 
    [Total Math Test Attempts] = s.sum_math, 
    [Total Science Test Attempts] = s.sum_science
FROM [SchoolGrade] AS SG INNER JOIN
     TempTable AS s
     ON S.schoolgrade_id = SG.id
```

Clean up:

```
DROP TABLE TempTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to aggregate before doing the `JOIN`.  I think this will work in MS Access:

```
UPDATE SG
    SET [Total Reading Test Attempts] = s.sum_reading, 
        [Total Math Test Attempts] = s.sum_math, 
        [Total Science Test Attempts] = s.sum_science
    FROM [SchoolGrade] AS SG INNER JOIN
         (SELECT s.schoolgrade_id,
                 SUM([Reading Test Attempts]) as sum_reading,
                 SUM([Math Test Attempts]) as sum_math,
                 SUM([Science Test Attempts]) as sum_science
          FROM [Student] AS s
          GROUP BY s.schoolgrade_id
         ) s
         ON S.schoolgrade_id = SG.id
```

Comment: I get the following error:
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 's.sum_science
    FROM [SchoolGrade] AS SG INNER JOIN
         (SELECT s.schoolgrade_id,
                 SUM([Reading Test Attempts]) as sum_reading,
                 SUM([Math Test Attempts]) as sum_math,
                 SUM([Science Test Attempts]) as sum_science
          FROM [Student] AS s
          GROUP BY s.schoolgrade_id
         ) s
         ON S.schoolgrade_id = SG.id'.

Comment: It is missing the `AS` for the `s` alias.  Also, Access will not perform updates with JOINS to queries. If you attempt that, it returns the error 'Operation must use an updatable query'.  See [Use SELECT inside an UPDATE query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871905/use-select-inside-an-update-query).

Comment: C Perkins Creating a table to update from worked! Thank You!