# Update specific table column with select query data MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2019 and ahve two tables:

- table_a (id_a, number_a)
- table_b (id_b, name_b)

This `UPDATE` statement doesn't work:

```
UPDATE table_a
SET number_a = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_b WHERE id_b IN (1,3) AND name_b=@name) 
WHERE id_a=1;
```

**Error**

> Operation must use an updateable query

Comment: https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use SELECT inside an UPDATE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871905/use-select-inside-an-update-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_a 
SET table_a.number_a = DCount("*","table_b","id_b IN (1,3) AND name_b=@name")
WHERE table_a.id_a=1;
```

or

```
UPDATE table_a 
SET table_a.number_a = DCount("*","table_b","id_b IN (1,3) AND name_b=" & @name)
WHERE table_a.id_a=1;
```

depends on what is `@name`, where it is defined and how it is substituted with its value.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you capture value then assign it like below

```
DECLARE @COUNT_B INT
SELECT @COUNT_B = COUNT(*) FROM table_b WHERE id_b IN (1,3) GROUP BY id_b

UPDATE table_a
SET number_a = @COUNT_B
WHERE id_a=1;
```

Comment: This is not valid syntax for MS Access.